# Cannot import arcpy in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, arcgis, esri, arcpy

I am new to Python and am trying to use PyCharm, mostly to use ArcPy.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1, which comes with Python 3.6. I have a server license with my company. I just downloaded PyCharm (community version) and am trying to `import arcpy`. However, after I type `import` I do not see `arcpy` come up as an option. I can run `import arcpy`, but it doesn't have any effect. There is no module that is actually imported, and I can't seem to access the arcpy tools.

I have my project configured to Python 3.6. When I try to install a package, I do not see any called '`arcpy`'. There are other accessory packages to `arcpy`, such as `arcpyext`, but they do not allow me to import `arcpy`.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check if the PyCharm project is configured to use the same python interpreter in which you isntalled ArcGIS? Perhaps this was installed on a particular virtualenv?

Comment: Did you [install it via Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)?

Comment: @torresmateo -Yes, I believe so. I configured the project to Python 3.6 from the ArcGIS Pro folder location.

Comment: @RandomDavis Apparently I did not install the proper package. I should have installed 'arcpyext'. After that, it worked. If you want to answer I will accept your response as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution was to install the package `arcpyext` via Pycharm via their pre-prescribed method: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Shoot, I'm so sorry, that actually didn't work like I thought. It only works if Python 2.7 is configured, but I need to use Python 3.6.

Comment: If you configure Python 3.6 and then install, what happens?

Comment: I don't think arcpyext is the proper package to install... it is just an extension to arcpy.

Comment: So if you install just `arcpy` via that linked method, what happens? Are you certain that that package has a 3.6 or 3.x-compatible version released?

Comment: There is no package called 'arcpy' listed as an available package. However, my version of ArcPro uses Python 3.6, and the command 'import arcpy' is in every example code. [https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/describing-data.htm]

Comment: @JessicaMarie does this help at all? https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/how-can-i-get-the-arcpy-module-to-load-in-python-3-6/td-p/717616

Comment: I read that, and the only solution it seems to offer is to uninstall Python 2.7. I'll follow up with the results.